# Maven : Should I keep or remove declared dependencies that are also transitives dependencies?

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, dependency-management

Do you think it is a good practice to remove every transitive dependencies that can be found in a maven pom?

Example:
My project depends on A and B.
B is also a transitive dependency of A.
Should I keep B in my pom or remove it ?

What is the best:
having all known jars, even transitive one, declared on the pom or keeping only the top level jars ?

This is a little bit subjective, but I am trying to clean some huge poms (parent and children) with a lot of transitive dependencies. I want to keep my pom as simple as possible, but I want also them to be maintainable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your project has direct dependencies on B then you should keep it even if B is a transitive dependency of A. It can be that in the next version A won't use B an you'll have to restructure the pom.xml.

Generally, Maven dependencies should reflect the logical project dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I like this advice: 'reflect the logical project dependencies'

Comment: Don't you think that you should make a distinction here between internal and external dependencies? I had similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800571/are-there-any-reasons-to-keep-explicit-dependency-declaration-for-my-own-transit I still can't see a reason why I should bother with declaring all the dependencies between my own modules. If APIs will change and the project would fail to compile, then I would fix it and most likely improve the code maintainability along the way :)

Comment: How is the link related to the question/answer?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I've started MSTP as a plugin to analyze project dependencies and give recommendations what to include as a direct dependency and what to remove. This is exactly the question being asked here. However, I've never got to the production release, so I'll edit out the [link](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MSTP/Home).

Answer (score 15):

I would *prefer* to **avoid the declaration of the transitive dependencies**, and explicitly include them in the pom if there is a good reason for that. Here are my arguments:

- I try to **keep the pom as simple as possible**. With the transitive dependencies declared, even if they are used explicitly, the Maven pom becomes more verbose.

By declaring the transitive dependencies (even if you explicitly need them):

- *Redundancy in the declaration is introduced*, because this information is already in the pom descriptor of the *artifact that is required*.
- If a new version of the *artifact required* does not depend on the `transitive dependency` anymore, you have to remove the `transitive dependency` from your assembly yourself, if that `transitive dependency` is explicitly declared.
- The information for the transitivity gets manipulated by declaring the transitive dependency explicitly.

**It would make sense** to include a dependency explicitly in the following case:

- You have one two dependencies, say `C` and `D`, that require different versions of the transitive dependency `B`  (or you require a specific version of `B` in your project). In this case you have to choose a version of `B` and explicitly define the transitive dependency `T`. (*)

**Conclusion**:
I would try to avoid the declaration, unless it makes sense to declare the artifact specifically (like in the case (*)).

Comment: If you want to participate in the similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800571/are-there-any-reasons-to-keep-explicit-dependency-declaration-for-my-own-transit