# Are there any reasons to keep explicit dependency declaration for my own transitive dependencies in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have been reading for a while about an explicit versus transitive (implicit) dependency declaration in Maven. Most of the people tend to agree that you should always explicitly declare the libraries that your project depends on, mostly to avoid versions mismatch.

That is perfectly reasonable, but **how should we tackle our internal dependencies**? I see absolutely no reason to keep the explicit dependency between the modules, if they can be resolved via transitive mechanism.

My use case scenario:

- my team develops software in `major.minor.micro` release cycles, ex: 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.3.0, etc...
- with each release we increment the versioning scheme for all of our modules in the project (so A:1.0, B:1.0 become A:1.1, B:1.1)
- we are using reactor projects, nested as far as two levels deep

My gut is telling me - get rid of the dependency spaghetti. Anyone will prove me wrong? Reactor (dependencies) graphs are more than welcome :-)

## An example:

My parent project uses following modules (external dependencies omitted):

```
Project:1.1   
 - core:1.1
 - +-- util:1.1 
 -   +-- xml-helper:1.1
 - logic:1.1
 - +-- util:1.1 
 -   +-- xml-helper:1.1
 - gui:1.1
```

The question is: should I declare `xml-helper:1.1` as a dependency in `core`'s and `logic`'s pom.xml? That dependency will be automatically resolved (transitive) as I'm using `util` module.

If I declare it, I get a larger pom to maintain.

If I skip it, I might get into troubles when dependencies evolve over time.

Comment: Can you give an example of the scenario with pom file or may be create an example project on github or something similar.

Comment: I added a very basic example to the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a few questions here, so I'll try and answer them all.

> That is perfectly reasonable, but how should we tackle our internal
>   dependencies?

It looks like you have a module based project. To mitigate version conflicts I would suggest one of 2 possibilities:

1. Put your common dependencies in your parent modules
   `dependencyManagement` section, and use properties for your
   versions.
2. Use a base pom, and put your dependencies in its
   `dependencyManagement` section.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619732/27657) answer out for more information.

> My gut is telling me - get rid of the dependency spaghetti. Anyone
>   will prove me wrong?

I think this is a subjective question, and [may have been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4226756/27657) but I'll still give my opinion.

No. I think you're on the right track. I'm not totally sold on the "declare your transitive dependencies if you're using them" opinion. One of the great benefits of using maven is that you get the transitive dependencies. If you had to declare dependencies for **everything** you used, I'd imagine that your poms would grow to be unmanageable beasts pretty quickly.

> The question is: should I declare xml-helper:1.1 as a dependency in
>   core's and logic's pom.xml?

Again, I would lean towards using `dependencyManagement` as opposed to declaration in each pom.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I forgot to add that we of course use dependency management section in the parent pom :-) The questions is purely about declaring transitive dependencies. Now that I think about it, there is also another point against it. If your top module like `core` makes use of just one utility method from `xml-helper` and this method was removed from the project at some point, you still have the strong dependency in the POM between the modules which have no longer anything in common. This makes management even harder and can be only picked up by `dependency:analyze` goal.

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman please accept the answer above if it was useful or start bounty to take attention to receive more answers.