# What do I need to build JDK 9 project with non-modular dependencies using Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I have a simple Java 9 SE project with one dependency on a non-modularized project (chose Weld SE for this example) and I am trying to build it with Maven (`clean install`).In order for Java 9 to kick in, I have added `module-info.java`. Originally, this file only contained module name and had no `requires` formulas.

Please bear in mind that my sole dependency is NOT a modular project, therefore I presumed Maven will put in the classpath (not module-path) and hence it will end up in the `unnamed module` as described in [State of the modular system](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#unnamed-modules).

Now, my Maven version is 3.3.9 and I am aware that I need to use Maven compiler plugin in version 3.6, as [described here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html) Of course I have downloaded JDK 9 EA build with jigsaw and set Maven to use that.

If I build my project without `module-info.java`, everything works, stuff is added to classpath and build succeeds. I suppose Maven just sticks to the old ways as long as you leave out that file.

However building it *with* `module-info.java` tells me that the classes from my dependency cannot be found on the classpath. So I ran Maven in debug mode (with -X) and indeed - **all jars are under module-path and classpath is empty**. This effectively means that all my dependencies are **transferred into [automatic modules](https://github.com/manovotn/JDK9Playground/blob/master/src/main/java/module-info.java)** and I need to declare them in `module-info.java`.

Once I declare the [automatic module requirements](https://github.com/manovotn/JDK9Playground/blob/master/src/main/java/module-info.java)(link to projects's `module-info`), **I am able to build it on JDK 9**. But it is kind of messy - my only `pom.xml` dependecy is on `weld-se-core`, yet my `module-info` requires me to declare *a lot more requirements* for compilation to pass.

Here is a whole [GitHub project](https://github.com/manovotn/JDK9Playground) where all this can be observed.

So my questions are:

1. *Can I tell Maven to put some artifacts on classpath if I know they are not modularized? So that I can avoid the `automatic module` and the need to declare them?*
2. *If I stick with `automatic module`, can I tell Maven to somehow transitively allow anything my dependency needs to bring in? E.g. other parts of Weld, CDI API etc.*
3. *What is the actual reason, why I need to state, that my project `requires` modules, which I **do not use directly? E.g. [`weld.environment.common`](https://github.com/manovotn/JDK9Playground/blob/master/src/main/java/module-info.java#L6)***

Comment: That page is a bit outdated, the compiler plugin 3.6.0 is now out. Are you using this release version? Could you post your current project, and a sample POM?

Comment: Forgot to add - I am aware that its outdated and I use released versions where applicable. I'll create a simpler version of the project and update the question by tomorrow. But basically I took [this project](https://github.com/manovotn/log-uploader/blob/master/pom.xml) and tried to turn it into JDK 9 aware one. (by adding module-info and updating those maven plugins)

Comment: Did you check [that page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html) as well? You need to define 2 execution blocks for projects that are Java 8 compatible

Comment: Can't help you with the Maven details but there's one thing you got wrong. All of your module's dependencies need to be declared in the `module-info.java`, even if they are not modules themselves. Those that are not modules must still be placed on the module path to be turning them into [automatic modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules).

Comment: @Tunaki Good link, thanks. I checked it and while it made few things clear, it didn't help.

Comment: @NicolaiParlog With your comment I actually managed to get it working. But it only raised more questions for me. I have updated the question. I don't really understand why Maven behaves in this manner, why do I get automatic module instead of unnamed module. And why I need to declare requirements for modules I do not use directly :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including few of the recent updates, I would *try* and answer this.

> #### UPDATE

- Java 9 was released publically on 21.09.2017.
- The [minimum compatible version](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) of `maven-compiler-plugin` in today's date is `3.7.0`.

  As already shared by @Tunaki on how you can configure it to build compatible versions for both [JDK 1.5 to 8 and JDK 9](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html).

Assuming from the question and comments, you are already aware of [automatic modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules) and placing all the module dependencies on the module path.

> > Can I tell Maven to put some artifacts on classpath if I know they are not modularized? So that I can avoid the automatic module and the need to declare them?

For artifacts specified in the maven pom `<dependencies>` and the ones which are as well not included in the `module-info.java` of the current module are ultimately left behind to be accessed from the classpath in form of an *[unnamed module.](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module)*

> > If I stick with automatic module, can I tell Maven to somehow transitively allow anything my dependency needs to bring in? E.g. other parts of Weld, CDI API etc.

**No**, since the automatic modules do not consist of an explicitly declared `module-info.java`, there is no such way of defining ***[`requires transitive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46502563/1746118)*** for any transitive dependency that might be required by the present module.

From one of my [past experiences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352120/incompatible-types-equality-constraints-and-method-not-found-during-java-9-migr), any Maven transitive dependency as detailed in the `dependency:tree` that is needed at compile time by the module would have to be explicitly defined using `requires` in the `module-info` of the current project.

> > What is the actual reason, why I need to state, that my project requires modules, which I do not use directly? E.g. weld.environment.common**

- You do not need to specify `requires` for modules that are not required at compile or runtime by your module.
- In case there is a dependency that is not required at runtime but required at compile time by your project, you would need to make sure that you define such module using ***[`requires static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46537365/1746118)*** in your declarations.

  I would have preferably practiced a similar approach at present as well, as stated in the answer to [should I keep or remove declared dependencies that are also transitive dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226756/maven-should-i-keep-or-remove-declared-dependencies-that-are-also-transitives)

Comment: I pretty much figured all I asked some (long?) time ago, but I forgot that I asked this in the first place - shame on me. Your answer sums it up nicely, I'll accept it.

Comment: For maven-compiler version `3.7.0` just have in mind [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-336)

Comment: @MarinosAn I see for the compatibility issue that you are pointing out. Thanks for sharing. I guess I moved to 3.8.0 and above for related compatibility issue and updated JDKs on personal projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help to tell maven to use java 9 :

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a `module-info.java` file, you will need to declare all the java modules except `java.base` you need as you are now using jigsaw.

Using `mvn dependency:tree` can help you in populating this but you are not required to use `module-info.java`  in Java 9.