# Spring: @Resource injection stopped working under JDK9

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, java-9

In my `@Configuration` class I have dependendies like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Resource(name = "firstDataSource")
    private DataSource firstDataSource;

    // more code
}
```

The dependency injection worked in Oracle JDK 8: `firstDataSource` field was successfully injected with a non-null value.

Now I tried to run the application (with no modifications) in JDK 9. The result is that `@Resource` does not trigger dependency injection anymore: everything annotated with this annotation remains `null`.

What could be the reason for `@Resource` to stop working?

Spring 4.0.9 is used in the project.

Here is a test project demonstrating the problem: https://github.com/rpuch/test-spring-injection-jdk9

It contains a single test: `MainTest` which I run from my IDE. When I use JDK 8, it outputs

```
сен 29, 2017 10:45:13 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5f8ed237: startup date [Fri Sep 29 22:45:13 SAMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
OK
```

But under JDK 9, it throws an exception during startup which is caused by the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: bean1 is not injected
    at Bean2.<init>(Bean2.java:7)
    at Config2.bean2(Config2.java:16)
```

which happens when the dependency is not injected.

Comment: What package does the `@Resource` belong to? Did [your code compiled successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352120/incompatible-types-equality-constraints-and-method-not-found-during-java-9-migr)? Is there a reproducible instance to test this?

Comment: It is `javax.annotation.Resource`. Yes, everything compiles correctly. I will try to create a test project to reproduce this.

Comment: And how do you import/add that package in your project module?

Comment: If by 'module' you mean java module (in the sense of Jigsaw), then I don't have module-info.java as we can't yet depend on Java 9 specific features. Should I import it specifically?

Comment: Yes, I meant [tag:java-module]  only. And in that case, you might to share some error/debug log as well with the reproducible instance.

Comment: Alas, I don't see anything relevant in my log before I get a `NullPointerException` because a non-injected field is accessed during startup.

Comment: In case you are using framework like maven/gradle, could you add to the question, your project's existing *dependency tree*.

Comment: I've added a test project at github, question updated.

Comment: Which version of Spring is this? Spring 5 seems to be the first version to support JDK 9.

Comment: @AlanBateman Spring version is 4.0.9. I also tried 4.3.11 and 5.0.0, they behave in the same way.

Comment: Does this fix it: `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>`? If so then I think we can explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Indeed, this fixes the problem, thanks! But how come? I mean, `@Resource` is alreasy at the JDK classpath even without this dependency.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy The javax.annotation being deprecated in jdk9 is possibly the cause of what you're facing.

Comment: Someone needs to write a complete answer but in summary: Java SE defines a small subset of the JSR-250 annotations, just enough to support web services. The module in the JDK with these annotations is not resolved by default. It is "as if" these annotations don't exist. This is the first step to dropping this module from Java SE and the JDK. The reason it builds for you is because your POM is configured to compile with -source/-target 8. If your POM didn't have these properties then I assume it wouldn't compile either.

Comment: @AlanBateman True, if the source and target 9 are used instead of 1.8, it wouldn't compile asking for a module for the annotation at the very first step.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `java.xml.ws.annotation` being deprecated in jdk9 is possibly the cause of what you're facing. Since the annotation `@Resource` is from the package `javax.annotation` exported by the same module.

You might want to provide [javatm-common-annotations](https://github.com/javaee/javax.annotation#javatm-common-annotations) as an upgradeable module for **[`java.xml.ws.annotation`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.xml.ws.annotation-summary.html)** which exports the javax.annotation.

> This standalone release of Java(TM) Common Annotations uses a Java Platform Module System "automatic" module name of java.annotation, to match the 
>   module name used in JDK 9.

The search on [central suggests](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.annotation%7Cjavax.annotation-api%7C1.3.1%7Cjar), you can use:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This runs fine on my machine with your shared code.

---

Also, a note about the code that you've shared. Since you're migrating to using JDK9, you should migrate to using latest [springframework](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-context%7C5.0.0.RELEASE%7Cjar) dependencies [released as on 28-9-2017](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/28/spring-framework-5-0-goes-ga):-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

***Edit*** : Do take a look at [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501720/1746118) for an alternate to make use of `--add-modules` in case you are not planning to migrate to the `javaee` explosed module yet.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a few missing details.

Spring `@Resource`-driven injection only works when `javax.annotation.Resource` is available at run time. Spring makes a check:

```
private static final boolean jsr250Present =
        ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.annotation.Resource", AnnotationConfigUtils.class.getClassLoader());
```

and then uses that `jsr250Present` variable to see whether `@Resource`-based injection (and also `@PostConstruct`/`@PreDestroy` functionality) should be enabled.

In my case, under JDK 9, this class was not available in run time because it belongs to a separate module `java.ws.xml.annotation` (separate from the basic `java.base` module containing `java.lang` and some other packages that is always available). To solve the problem, one of the following approaches may be taken:

1. Add `javax.annotation-api` library to my application classpath, as @AlanBateman and @nullpointer suggested.
2. As an alternative, `java` may be instructed to add the module using a command line switch: `--add-modules java.xml.ws.annotation`. This leaves the code intact.