# How to get access to javax.annotation.Resource at run time in Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I have a test:

```
public class ResourceTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("javax.annotation.Resource");
    }
}
```

It tries to access `javax.annotation.Resource`. In java 8 it worked, but in java 9 (I'm using Oracle JDK 9) it fails with `ClassNotFoundException`. 
As explained here [Spring: @Resource injection stopped working under JDK9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494522/spring-resource-injection-stopped-working-under-jdk9/46501720#46501720) , `javax.annotation.Resource` from the JDK is not available by default in Java 9.

I'm trying to get access to it using module descriptor:

```
module test {
    requires java.xml.ws.annotation;
    requires junit;
}
```

Here, I specifically request access to `java.xml.ws.annotation` module (which contains `javax.annotation.Resource`). But the test still fails.

When I remove that `requires` clause and add a dependency (as a library) which contains `javax.annotations.Resource`, it works:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I add them both (Maven dependency in `pom.xml` and `requires java.xml.ws.annotation`), compilation in IDEA fails with the following message:

```
the unnamed module reads package javax.annotation from both java.xml.ws.annotation and java.annotation
```

But Maven build still succeeds!

If I add `java.xml.ws.annotation` module via command line, it works (with no Maven dependency and **with** `requires` clause):

```
mvn clean test -DargLine="--add-modules java.xml.ws.annotation"
```

Do I do something wrong with my module description? How can I get access to JDK-supplied `javax.annotation.Resource` without command line switches?

The test project is available at https://github.com/rpuch/test-resource-jdk9

Comment: What happens when you just add the `--add-modules` argline and then `requires <modulename>`?

Comment: @nullpointer The test successfully runs in such a case (the class is successfully found).

Comment: The java.xml.ws.annotation module is deprecated for removal. You should look at just depending on the standalone version, meaning `requires java.annotation` and the Maven dependency on javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.1 as you have done. This eliminates the `--add-modules` from the usage too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to express dependency in maven on java ee features for transition to Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084751/how-to-express-dependency-in-maven-on-java-ee-features-for-transition-to-java-9)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just to clear out some confusion here. The ways to work stated in the question by you are alternatives and should not be combined as you have already seen.

> the unnamed module reads package javax.annotation from both
>   java.xml.ws.annotation and java.annotation

---

So the way it would work is either:

You can use the compiler args to add modules

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>9</release>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-modules</arg>
            <arg>java.xml.ws.annotation</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

### **OR**

Make use of the `javax.xml.ws.annotation` being an [upgradeable module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/goals-reqs/03#upgradeable-modules) which is when you can make use of the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Ideally this would be a preferrable option to stick to as the former is just an alternate to use the [@Deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.ws.annotation-summary.html) module marked `forRemoval`.

---

> So the required clause by itself it not enough to get access to a
>   module... is this true for all JDK-supplied modules (excluding
>   java.base), or it is only true for deprecated modules?

No, the `requires` is just a part of declaration. [Think about this, prior to JDK 9 if you used a statement `import some.foo.bar;` in your class which was not added as a library(classpath) would that have worked?]. The module marked as required has to be on the modulepath for you to access it.

---

***Update*** - The first option would not be supported any time longer with the use of JDK/11 or above wherein the JEP to [Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320) is targetted.

Comment: So the `required` clause by itself it not enough to get access to a module... is this true for all JDK-supplied modules (excluding `java.base`), or it is only true for deprecated modules?

Comment: Updated the answer fr this.

Comment: First option worked for me. (Didn't try second option)

Comment: The javax.annotation and other JavaEE classes are scheduled for removal in Java 11, per [JEP-320](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320), so the first option will no longer work in never versions.

Comment: @JoepWeijers Agreed. Would update the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: @JoepWeijers The first version will work if you provide a dependency to `javax.annotation-api` as well.

Comment: @nullpointer please, can you elaborate more option 2? What does it mean "Make use of the javax.xml.ws.annotation being an upgradeable module"? How would this be translated in the `pom.xml`?

Comment: thanks so much for sharing this solution. For java 8 the second option (direct dependency) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For gradle build, adding the following to build.gradle works:

```
compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}
```