# Java 9 migration javax.annotation

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-module

So i try to migrate my project to Java 9 but the process seems not so easy as i thought it would be. I kept getting some errors about invisible packages that i could fix with the following argument in my pom:

```
<compilerArgs>
     <arg>--add-modules</arg>
     <arg>java.se.ee</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

But i still get the following error:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Priority
[ERROR]   location: package javax.annotation
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you read [Java 9: how to get access to javax.annotation.Resource at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502001/java-9-how-to-get-access-to-javax-annotation-resource-at-run-time)? If yes, please explain what else did you tried and how is this not a duplicate.

Comment: javax.annotation.Priority is not in Java SE or the JDK. If you have javax.annotation-api-1.3.1.jar (maven coordinates: javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.1) on your class path then it should work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 9: how to get access to javax.annotation.Resource at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502001/java-9-how-to-get-access-to-javax-annotation-resource-at-run-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure where `javax.annotation.Priority` comes from, but a solution [analog to getting JSR 305 running on Java 9](https://blog.codefx.org/java/jsr-305-java-9/) should fix your problem: Instead of adding the (deprecated) Java EE module *java.xml.ws.annotation* (which you do indirectly by adding *java.se.ee*), you should instead add the `javax.annotation` package from an external artifact, namely [*javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api*](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax.annotation%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javax.annotation-api%22).

If you modularize your code, that solution no longer works and you have to start [patching modules](https://blog.codefx.org/java/jsr-305-java-9/#Modular-Project). Or, even better, move away from solutions that require non-JDK classes that pretend to come from `java` or `javax` packages because that will always cause problems.