# Running existing application with Java9 causes Guice Injector error with PreDestroy

Tags: java, guice, java-9

Just to check if it runs I tried to run my Java8 compiled application with the current Oracle JDK9 (9.0.1). When starting up guice gets a ClassNotFoundExceptionf for javax.annotation.PreDestroy which is contained in a jar on the classpath.
I'm using the JSR-250 extensions: http://code.mycila.com/guice/

In Java8 it runs as usual. So I'm wondering why the JDK 9 is not backwards compatible just for the runtime environment. Have I missed something to get it to work? Or do I have to configure the module path and compile my application in Java9 to get it running with the Java9 runtime?

Here is the stack trace: (full part is here: https://pastebin.ca/3894786)

> c.g.i.Guice An exception was caught and reported. Message:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy
>   java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.annotation.PreDestroy
>   not present
>
> at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(Unknown
>   Source)

Comment: Generally speaking, you do not have to recompile or use the module path. Just putting it on a JVM 9 class path should work. Are you sure that the class path contains `PreDestroy`? Because it looks like it doesn't and you've been relying on the JDK package `javax.annotation`. The module containing it [is no longer resolved by default](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules).

Comment: @nullpointer: thanks for the link it seems that this is the issue. so it is not backwards compatible in that case.

Comment: Related to [Spring: @Resource injection stopped working under JDK9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494522/spring-resource-injection-stopped-working-under-jdk9/46495550#46495550) and do take a look at (2) in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501720/1746118) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running your application with the following VM flag:

```
--add-modules java.xml.ws.annotation
```

Comment: java.xml.ws.annotation is a subset of the annotations that were defined for JAX-WS use. Better to add the java.annotation module to the module path, or just add its artifact to the class path.