# How to suppress the "requires transitive directive for an automatic module" warning properly?

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-module

After upgrading a Maven project to Java 9 and adding a module descriptor, `javac` complains about a **transitive dependency for an automatic module:**

> **[WARNING] /.../src/main/java/module-info.java:[3,35] `requires transitive` directive for an automatic module**

An example `module-info.java` to reproduce the problem:

```
module com.example.mymodule {
    exports com.example.mymodule.myexportedpackage;
    requires transitive com.google.common;
}
```

The *meaning* of this warning is completely clear, here are some related links:

- [What's the difference between requires and requires transitive statements in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502453/whats-the-difference-between-requires-and-requires-transitive-statements-in-jav)
- [Why does javac complain about named automatic-modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750408/why-does-javac-complain-about-named-automatic-modules)
- [Related OpenJDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178011)

The question is — **how to suppress this warning,** without fixing the actual issue, and without disabling all the other `javac` warnings?

I've tried the following options, but none of them worked:

- `@SuppressWarnings("module")` in `module-info.java`
- `@SuppressWarnings("all")` in `module-info.java`
- `-Xlint:all,-module` command line option

---

Unfortunately, I cannot fix the actual issue (for now) because "my" module has return types and annotations from third-party (automatic) modules (e.g. Guava). Thus, if I'd use "requires com.google.common" (without `transitive`), then there would be a different warning, e.g.:

> [WARNING] .../MyClass.java:[25,20] class `com.google.common.collect.Table` in module `com.google.common` is not indirectly exported using `requires transitive`

And of course I cannot define module descriptors for the third-party libraries (which are automatic modules right now).

I'm using `-Werror` which I'd prefer to keep, so the warning isn't merely annoying...

---

P.S. I do not intend to publish my artifacts to any public repositories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try out the option of switching off the warning using

```
-Xlint:-requires-transitive-automatic
```

The changes for which were merged with [JDK-8178011](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178011) stating:-

> There should be two new warnings:
>
> - when a named module "requires transitive" an automatic module (default on)
> - when a named module "requires" an automatic module (default off)

Inferring this [from the changes made here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/langtools/rev/98108b7d4cb6) and also from the edit to the [JEP 261: Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) which confirms that(emphasis mine):-

> In both of the modular modes the compiler will, by default, generate
>   various warnings related to the module system; these may be disabled
>   via the option `-Xlint:-module`.
>
> More precise control of these warnings
>   is available via the *exports, opens, requires-automatic, and
>   requires-transitive-automatic keys for the `-Xlint` option*.

Comment: I've tried `-Xlint:-requires-transitive-automatic` and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: I also added `-Xlint:-requires-automatic`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also just use `@SuppressWarnings` like so:

```java
@SuppressWarnings({ "requires-automatic", "requires-transitive-automatic" })
module foo {
 // ...
}
```

The [JDK itself uses this technique](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/test/langtools/tools/javac/modules/AutomaticModules.java#L560-L564).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the accepted answer didn't help me.
*BTW, I am using Java 14 with a bunch of module system hacks for JUnit.*

I had to add another flag, so the complete list looks as following:

```
-Xlint:-exports -Xlint:-requires-transitive-automatic -Xlint:-requires-automatic
```

I have searched for the error message and found the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jigsaw/jake/langtools/rev/9d791b717b5c). There, one can see that the corresponding compiler key is called `compiler.warn.leaks.not.accessible.not.required.transitive`, with the command line arg `-Xlint:exports`.