# Do Kotlin 1.2.10 and Java 9 have opposite rules regarding automatic modules?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, java-platform-module-system, java-module

I have a Gradle project using the Kotlin Gradle plugin. I want to build a Java 9 module, so my directory structure looks like this:

```
src/main/java/
    - module-info.java
src/main/kotlin/
    - Foo.kt
    - Bar.kt
build.gradle
...
```

My `build.gradle` declares the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.10"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.10"
    compile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.2"
}
```

and I use all of these dependencies in my Kotlin source (`Foo.kt`, `Bar.kt`, ...).

Everything works hunky-dory if I write my `module-info.java` like so:

```
module my.module {
    requires kotlin.stdlib;
    exports my.module.pkg;
}
```

and if I supply all my compile-time dependencies to `javac` during the `compileJava` task using [this technique](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/).

*However* if I turn on `-Xlint:all` for the Java compiler during the `compileJava` task (to compile `module-info.java`), I get the following warnings:

```
/path/to/my.module/src/main/java/module-info.java:26: warning: requires directive for an automatic module
    requires kotlin.stdlib;
                   ^
```

So here we have the Java compiler, `javac` complaining that `kotlin.stdlib` is an automatic module so I shouldn't have a `requires` clause for it.

But if I delete the `requires` clause to make `javac` happy, it makes `kotlinc` even angrier than `javac` was (I get an error not a warning):

```
e: /path/to/my.module/src/main/java/module-info.java: The Kotlin standard library is not found in the module graph. Please ensure you have the 'requires kotlin.stdlib' clause in your module definition

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':my.module:compileKotlin'.
```

Now I can fix that, too, by editing my `compileKotlin` task thus:

```
compileKotlin {
    doFirst {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xallow-kotlin-package']
    }
}
```

But this only leads to MORE errors during the `compileKotlin` task, all looking like this one:

```
e: /path/to/my.module/src/main/kotlin/Foo.kt: (27, 30): Symbol is declared in module 'org.junit.jupiter.api' which current module does not depend on
```

And then if I try to force `compileKotlin` to take a module path rather than a classpath by adding `"-Xmodule-path=${classpath.asPath}"` to `freeCompilerArgs` and setting `classpath` to be empty, the Kotlin compiler can't find anything at all, and I end up with zillions of unresolved reference errors!

Why is the Kotlin compiler telling me I have to have `requires kotlin.stdlib;` when the Java compiler says the opposite? How can I get Kotlin and Java to work together to produce a Java 9 module?

Comment: did you try adding a `requires` directive for `org.junit.jupiter.api`? maybe this is what causes the last error from the kotlin compiler

Comment: @msrd0, I just tried it (hadn't done so before in isolation). Adding `org.junit.jupiter.api` into the `module-info.java` as a `requires` *does* get rid of the unresolved symbol reference errors. HOWEVER, again, it generates an `-Xlint:all` warning from `javac` which doesn't want `requires` on automatic modules. So again it seems like Kotlin and Java are enforcing different rules here.

Comment: did you try it together with the `-Xallow-kotlin-package` flag?

Comment: @msrd0 - yes: With and without. Neither works although both generate different errors. Essentially all `-Xallow-kotlin-package` allows me to do is omit `requires kotlin.stdlib;` from my `module-info.java` thus saving one `javac` warning.

Comment: Well, I added a comment to your previous question. Ideally, this could be solved in two ways, (1) if you could live with the warnings you could wait for the dependency you rely on, to move to JPMS(module system itself first) (2) you can go ahead and modify the jar being used to get rid of the warning using the MANIFEST entry.

Answer (score 3):

If you're authoring Java 9 module in Kotlin, you have to declare `requires kotlin.stdlib` in your `module-info.java` in order to satisfy runtime dependencies of the compiled Kotlin code in addition to the explicit dependencies on the standard library API.

`javac` warns you about requiring an automatic module when lint is enabled, because automatic modules have some potential [drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module) compared to normal modules. Until the standard library is compiled as a normal module, you have to deal with this warning.

`-Xallow-kotlin-package` compiler flag allows you to omit `require kotlin.stdlib`, because it is intended to be used only when the standard library itself is compiled. Obviously, if you specify this flag and omit that requirement, you won't be able to use any API from the standard library, so this is not really an option for you.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easiest to simply suppress the warnings for use of an automatic module. (In my case I have to use some automatic modules whether I want to or not, so these warnings are just distracting noise.) I have the following in my build.gradle.kts:

```
val compilerArgs = listOf(
    "-Xlint:all",                           // Enable all warnings except...
    "-Xlint:-requires-automatic",           // Suppress "requires directive for an automatic module" warnings from module-info.java
    "-Xlint:-requires-transitive-automatic" // Suppress "requires transitive directive for an automatic module" warnings from module-info.java
)

// This task will compile all Java code in the target module except for test code.
tasks.compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs.addAll(compilerArgs)
    }
}

// This task will compile all Java test code in the target module.
tasks.compileTestJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs.addAll(compilerArgs)
    }
}
```