# java 10 gradle project : automatic module not found

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, guava, java-module

I created a java 10 project with intelliJ, using gradle.
I copied some stuff into it (some "AppFx" class using the library guava and javaFx, and a personal build.gradle file).
I also added a module-info.java file in src/main/java with this content:

```
module biblio5.main {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires guava;
}
```

in which grava is an automatic module.

here is the relevant part of build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
}
```

intelliJ can compile the project (using the hammer-like icon) but when I run the compileJava gradle task from intelliJ, I get an error:

> 13:12:46: Executing task 'compileJava'...
>
> > Task :compileJava FAILED C:\Users\lolve\Documents\gradle_java\biblio5\src\main\java\module-info.java:5:
> >     error: module not found: guava
> >         requires guava;
> >                  ^ 1 error

I spent a lot of time on the net but did not manage to find an answer.

thank you

ps: here is the entire build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
        classpath 'eu.appsatori:gradle-fatjar-plugin:0.3'
    }
    repositories {

        maven {url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins/javafx-gradle-plugin"}
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        jcenter()
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.4'
}
apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'eu.appsatori.fatjar'

group 'lorry'
version '1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.10

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    maven {url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins/javafx-gradle-plugin"}
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }

}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
}

//********************************************************************************************
launch4j {
    outfile='bibliotek-v3.exe'
    mainClassName = 'lorry.AppFx'
    icon = "${projectDir}\\icons\\hands2.ico"
    copyConfigurable = project.tasks.fatJar.outputs.files
    //jar = "lib/${project.tasks.fatJar.archiveName}"
    //headerType = "console"
    jar = "${buildDir}\\productFatJar\\fat.jar"
}

jar {
    baseName = 'executable3'
    version =  ''
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'lorry.AppFx'
        )
    }
}

task copyExecutable(type: Copy) {
    from file("${buildDir}\\launch4j\\bibliotek-v3.exe")
    into file("c:\\Users\\lolve\\Documents\\gradle_java\\produits")
}

task copyJar(type: Copy) {
    from file("${buildDir}\\jfx\\app\\bibliotek-v3.jar")
    into file("c:\\Users\\lolve\\Documents\\gradle_java\\produits")
}

task copyFatJar(type: Copy) {
    from file("${buildDir}\\productFatJar\\fat.jar")
    into file("c:\\Users\\lolve\\Documents\\gradle_java\\produits")
}

createExe.doLast{
    tasks.copyExecutable.execute()

}

task createJar(){
    doLast{
        tasks.jfxJar.execute()
        tasks.jfxNative.execute()
        tasks.copyJar.execute()
    }
}



jfx {
    jfxMainAppJarName = "bibliotek-v3.jar"
    // minimal requirement for jfxJar-task
    mainClass = 'lorry.AppFx'

    // minimal requirement for jfxNative-task
    vendor = 'lolveley'
}

fatJar {
    destinationDir=file("${buildDir}\\productFatJar")
    archiveName="fat.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'lorry.AppFx'
        )
    }
}

task createFats(){
    doLast{
        tasks.fatJar.execute()
        tasks.copyFatJar.execute()

        tasks.createExe.execute()

    }
}
```

EDIT

well, I made the change, and now I have "com.google.commons" instead guava in module-info.java, but I still get this error:

> Testing started at 14:20 ... 14:20:14: Executing task 'check'...
>
> > Task :compileJava FAILED C:\Users\lolve\Documents\gradle_java\biblio5\src\main\java\module-info.java:5:
> >     error: module not found: com.google.common
> >         requires com.google.common;
> >                            ^ 1 error

I changed gradle in intelliJ (the default option - recommended - was "default gradle wrapper") to my local gradle (v4.9), but without any effect.
What do you mean by "compatible with java"? What about try with a java 9 installation?

Comment: Gradle, by default, uses the _classpath_, not the _modulepath_, when compiling/running. I believe this is causing your problem. See [Building Java 9 Modules](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/). Unfortunately, according to that link Gradle _still_ doesn't have first-class support for Jigsaw modules (as of 4.10-rc-2).

Comment: My bad with the answer, I'd assumed that gradle(if updated) would be compatible with module path for Java9+ modular code. Just by the overview of the above document, [this](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_compilejava_code_task_to_produce_a_module) should be one of the section to look into

Comment: thank you, Slaw & nullpointer, adding the short code made it work. I can't mark the answer as accepted as there only remains commentaries, but if s/o make it as an answer, I soon will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***Update:** Gradle 6.4 added basic support for Jigsaw modules. See [this sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_multi_project.html) in the documentation (which also links to other related documentation). Note that the* Building Java 9 Modules *article linked to in this answer has changed significantly since this answer was posted.*

---

The issue is Gradle *still* (as of 4.10-rc-2) doesn't have first-class support for Jigsaw modules. All the tasks will use the *classpath*, not the *modulepath*, when executing. This obviously will cause issues when trying to create a modular library/application (with `module-info.java`).

If you want to use Jigsaw modules in your project you should read [Building Java 9 Modules](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/). Your scenario, as @nullpointer [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917106/java-10-gradle-project-automatic-module-not-found/51918271?noredirect=1#comment90785382_51917106), is best covered by [this section](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_compilejava_code_task_to_produce_a_module) of the linked document. The takeaway is to add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
ext.moduleName = 'your.module'

compileJava {
    inputs.property('moduleName', moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

They also have sections for modifying the `compileTestJava` task ([here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_compiletestjava_code_task_to_locally_alter_the_module)) and the `test` task ([here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_test_code_task_to_consume_the_locally_altered_module)). Personally, I tend to not modify those tasks as testing often requires a lot of reflection which in turn requires a lot of `--add-opens` arguments. If you find out that's not true (haven't tried it in a while) or there's a better way, please let me know.

If your Gradle project is an `application` you also want to read [the section](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#step_3_consume_java_9_modules_in_the_code_run_code_and_code_assemble_code_tasks) covering the `run` and `assemble` tasks.

There is an experimental Gradle plugin that does all this for you: [`experimental-jigsaw`](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#step_4_use_the_code_experimental_jigsaw_code_plugin_to_do_the_same_thing). The plugin is limited, however, and there is a fork on GitHub, named [`chainsaw`](https://github.com/zyxist/chainsaw), that adds more features. *Note: I don't know how maintained either plugin is.*

Another Gradle plugin is available: [Gradle Modules Plugin](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin).

If you want to watch for updates regarding Jigsaw support in Gradle they maintain [an epic](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/890) on GitHub.

---

Also, to include what @nullpointer [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917106/java-10-gradle-project-automatic-module-not-found/51918271?noredirect=1#comment90786590_51918271), you should be using a version of Guava that includes an `Automatic-Module-Name` entry in its manifest. Without this entry (combined with no `module-info`) the name of the module is subject to the name of the `jar` file; which may change unexpectedly. In other words, the `Automatic-Module-Name` entry makes for a better contract regarding the name of an automatic module. The first version that Guava added this entry is [23.2](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v23.2):

> **Changelog**
>
> - Added [JPMS](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/) module name `com.google.common` for Guava.
>
> ...

However, the most recent version (as of writing this answer) is [26.0](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v26.0).

More information about automatic modules can be found:

- in the Javadoc of [`ModuleFinder.of(Path...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of(java.nio.file.Path...))
- [this section](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules) of *The State of the Module System*
- and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module)

Comment: Just to add to all of the above. The part about using the updated version of the library shall still make sense, since the explicitly added `Automatic-Module-Name: com.google.common` is a clearer contract to make use of a library as an automatic module.