# Is there a JMS module for Java 9 JPMS?

Tags: java, jms, java-9, java-module

While playing around with the Java 9 Platform Module System (JPMS), I couldn't find a module containing the `javax.jms` package.

[Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis) lists replacements for several JEE APIs, but not JMS.
Several jars are available containing this package (i.e. `javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0.1` in the Maven repo), but none that I could find are *automatic modules*, i.e. none of them have `Automatic-Module-Name` in their manifest.

Is there a JMS JPMS module available?
If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a JPMS module for the Java EE JMS API, but you might be able to use it as an [automatic module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module) even if it doesn't have the `Automatic-Module-Name` in its manifest.

There won't ever be a proper JPMS module for the Java EE JMS API, but there may someday be a JPMS module for the Jakarta EE version of the JMS API (Jakarta EE is the successor to Java EE).

Comment: Side note: I'd encourage you to take a step back and ask yourself what benefit you are gaining by using JPMS modules with your application. For a Desktop app JPMS might make sense, but for web apps (JavaEE, MicroProfile, Spring, etc) I don't see any benefit from utilizing JPMS

Comment: I was experimenting, so there was no *real* use case.