# How to resolve commons.math3 not found error in JavaFx project?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, module, dependencies

I am trying to make a javafx program that reads the data from the excel file. I have added the `poi` dependency in my project.

here is my `build.gradle` file code.

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
  id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

ext {
  junitVersion = '5.9.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
  mainModule = 'com.al_makkah_traders_app'
  mainClass = 'com.al_makkah_traders_app.Main'
}

javafx {
  version = '17.0.6'
  modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}



dependencies {
  implementation 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2'
  implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:3.0.0-alpha1'
  implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2'
  implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2'
  implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33'
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()}

jlink {
  imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
  options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
  launcher {
    name = 'app'
  }
}

jlinkZip {
  group = 'distribution'
}

jar {
  duplicatesStrategy = 'EXCLUDE'
  manifest {
    attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'com.al_makkah_traders_app.Main'
    )
  }
  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

Now when i try to run my project it throws an error stating that

```
> Task :Main.main() FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module commons.math3 not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi
```

and sometimes it throws an error stating that

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
    java.lang.module.FindException: Module SparseBitSet not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi.ooxml
```

I have been trying to solve this problem but i could not solve this problem. Although these modules exist in my project.

[image]

Comment: this solution worked for me. but isn't there any other method to solve this problem. I mean why this problem is actually happening and i want to know will be there any disadvantage to make a project non moduler? @jewelsea

Comment: did you add the "requires commons.math3;" to your module-info.java?

Comment: you may also have to export the commons packages explicitly in your gradle script: module('org.apache.commons:commons-math3', 'commons.math3') {
        exportAllPackages()
    }   example gradle script with apache math is here:  https://github.com/Birdasaur/Trinity/blob/main/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Make your project non-modular (delete the `module-info.java`).

If you need more info on that, see the info on non-modular projects in the getting started instructions at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io).  In particular, you will need to use VM options to place JavaFX modules on the module path as described in the openjfx.io instructions.

**Related**

You are using POI and Java, so also refer to the question below, which describes issues using the automatic modules that POI depends on in a Gradle setup:

- [Unable to launch a JavaFX application which uses Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984359/unable-to-launch-a-javafx-application-which-uses-apache-poi/73991163#73991163)

This is in addition to the issue in your question title about commons.math3.  But the core of the issue is still pretty similar: commons math3 is also an automatic module.

**FAQ**

This section is just explaining reasoning as requested in comments.  Some of the reasons are just opinions and are not core to the answer.

> why this problem is happening

[Understand Java modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

You have modules (java modules, not maven or gradle modules) that are required by dependent modules in your system, but are not on the module path (probably they are only on the classpath).

One of those modules (SparseBitSet) is an [automatic module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module) (it doesn't have a module-info).  You don't directly have a dependency on SparseBitSet, but your error message indicates it is transitively required by one of your poi dependencies.

Similarly, the commons math libraries you are relying on are also automatic modules.

I have limited experience with Gradle, but my experience is that Gradle places automatic modules on the classpath rather than the module path by default (you can override this through settings, but otherwise, as far as I know, that is how it works).

Relying on automatic modules for a modular project to work is inadvisable IMO, hence the non-modular recommendation.

> will there be any disadvantage to making a project non-modular?

Yes.

However, in this case, I believe the advantages outweigh the disadvantages. Benefits will be few, and the disadvantages will be painful.

Dependencies that were not originally designed to be modular can usually be made to work in a modular environment, but not necessarily.  Numerous things can go wrong with them, including [split package issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828014/how-split-packages-are-avoided-in-java-9).

IMO, it is more reliable to run software that wasn't built to be modular on the classpath rather than as modules.  Once you do that for some modules, you lose a lot of the benefits of using modules in the first place.

For example:

- you can't `jlink` automatic modules. `jlink` can only link modules with module-info.
- jars loaded from the classpath lose some benefits of modular encapsulation.

When you start to use automatic modules you have to suffer through the pain of using the module system (e.g. having to deal with the module accessibility issues you encountered in your question), while receiving few of the benefits.

Some software is only designed to be used as a module.  That includes all of the modules in the base JDK system for recent JDK distributions as well as the JavaFX modules.  Getting the JDK modules on the module path is pretty simple as that happens automatically.  Getting the JavaFX modules on the module path is more complex (the process is documented at openjfx.io).

Even if your application may not be modular, it can still use modular software as modules, in the way they were intended to be used (you don't lose the ability to use modular software).

If you intend to write a library that is used by others and you want them to be able to use that as a module (e.g. to enforce hiding of private API from library users), then you should make your code modular (include a module-info.java).  But if you are writing an application for deployment, this is not a concern.

The ecosystem of Java software is large.  Unfortunately, many important libraries and frameworks are not fully modularized (do not have module-info.java defined for all jars).  That includes large influential frameworks like Spring 6.  Even the [most recent beta release of math commons 4](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/tree/4.0-beta1-release/commons-math-core/src) does not include a module-info.java. Often it is better to write non-modular applications when you rely on such non-modular software (IMO).