# Eclipse throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver" exception, although I have put the JDBC driver in project's classpath

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, javafx, jdbc

I am building a log in system for a university project using JDBC and Eclipse IDE.As a GUI there are two TextFields for the username and password and a login button. For this purpose I made a class called BDConnection which does the connection with the database and the code of which is bellow:

```
package application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {

    private static final String username = "username";
    private static final String password = "password";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://dbname";
    
     static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        
        try {
            
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            
        }catch(SQLException eSQL) {
            eSQL.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return con;
    }
}
```

Also, because I use JavaFX I made another class the LoginSignUpController which contains the method that the login button listens to:

```
package application;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class LoginSignUpController {

    
    @FXML
    TextField usernameTxtField;
    
    @FXML
    PasswordField PasswdTxtFiled;
    
    private PreparedStatement prepStmnt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    
    
    public void login(ActionEvent e) {
        
        String user = usernameTxtField.getText();
        String passwd = PasswdTxtFiled.getText();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=? AND PASSWD=?";
        
        
        try {
            prepStmnt = DBConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);   
            
            prepStmnt.setString(1, user);
            prepStmnt.setString(2, passwd);

            rs = prepStmnt.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("User found");
            }else {
                System.out.println("User not found");
            }
            
            rs.close();
            prepStmnt.close();
            
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NullPointerException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
            
    }
    
}
```

The application keeps throwing me the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver", although I have added the JDBC driver in the classpath. I also tried to add the external jar in the module path but still nothing. What might be the issue?

Comment: "I also tried to add the external jar in the module path but still nothing" -> The Postgres driver isn't modular (at least last time I checked), it may not work well on the module path.  It may work as an [automatic module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module), but I don't know that that would be guaranteed for the driver.  For JavaFX projects that rely on software which is not a full module (contains `module-info` class), I recommend a non-modular setup as documented at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io).

Comment: I don't know that converting to a non-modular project will fix (or be required to fix) your current misconfiguration and postgres driver class access issue.

Comment: From the [Postgres documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/): "Prior to Java 1.6, the driver had to be loaded by the application: either by calling `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` or ... These older methods of loading the driver are still supported, but they are no longer necessary.".  the `forName` call is a reflection call, which is restricted in a modular environment unless the module is explicitly designed to be open to reflection.  I don't recommend using reflection on the driver.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: You may have put it on your projects classpath, but is it on your runtime classpath?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you were right, it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the others: The solution was to add the external JAR additionally to the runtime classpath, and not only to the projects classpath.

> "You may have put it on your projects classpath, but is it on your
> runtime classpath?" – Mark Rotteveel