# How to fix "auto module name cannot be used with jlink"?

Tags: java, javafx, bouncycastle, javafx-11, jlink

I've been working on a javafx application. Iam using Bouncy castle (for generating certificates) and google zxing library (for QR code generation). both these dependecies doesn't have a `module-info.class` file. When i try to run jlink it throws the following error

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jlink:3.1.0:jlink (default-cli) @ flexi ---
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.graphicsEmpty ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11\javafx-graphics-11.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.baseEmpty ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11\javafx-base-11.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: org.bouncycastle.provider ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.60\bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: com.google.zxing ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\com\google\zxing\core\3.5.0\core-3.5.0.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.base ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11\javafx-base-11-win.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.controls ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\11\javafx-controls-11-win.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.graphics ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11\javafx-graphics-11-win.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: com.github.rkdharun.flexi ( D:\Source\Flexi-desk\target\classes )
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.fxml ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11\javafx-fxml-11-win.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.fxmlEmpty ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11\javafx-fxml-11.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: javafx.media ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\11\javafx-media-11-win.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: org.bouncycastle.pkix ( C:\Users\dharu\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.60\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar )
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: org.bouncycastle.provider from file:///C:/Users/dharu/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.60/bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar
```

as long as i searched for this issue, it says that i should write the module-info file myself.
I have no idea how to do it and Iam a newbie.

Is there a possibility to package my application with all its dependency and jre if yes please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Bouncy 1.60 is over 5 years old. Any newer version -- even 1.61 -- does support modulosity.

Comment: JavaFX 11 is quite old and won't function on certain systems (e.g. M series Macs), I recommend a more recent version (e.g. 21+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in comments:

> Bouncy 1.60 is over 5 years old. Any newer version -- even 1.61 -- does support modularity.

But in general, you can't "fix" "auto module name cannot be used with jlink".  `jlink` (as of Java 21) does not support [automatic modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module).

The only solution to be able to link an automatic module, is to rebuild it as a standard module (with a `module-info.java`).  That is what the bouncy castle library developers did for latter versions of the bouncy castle libraries.

The other option is to not link the automatic modules into a jlink image and add them to the runtime later by placing them on the classpath or modulepath.

Alternately, you can use jpackage as that can create packages for non-modular software, though the result is different than what jlink does.

**Tools that assist in creating module-info for non-modular software**

- [ModiTect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) can generate module-info for dependencies that don't have it.
- The [badass jlink plugin](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) can work with non-modular dependencies (it creates a single jar for them and adds a synthetic module info).
- You can also unpack the jar, create and compile a module-info for it that you write yourself and add that to a repacked jar. [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//specs/man/jdeps.html) might be able to assist you in this task.

Detailed descriptions of how to use these tools is beyond the scope of what I am prepared to write here.  I advise you to study their documentation or relevant tutorials that use them, if you would like to try them.

None of these workarounds for non-modular dependencies is ideal nor guaranteed to work flawlessly for any non-modular software.  It is best to have module-info provided from the library developers when it is available.