# Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: spring.web

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javafx, java-17

I tried to use spring RestTemplate for my JavaFx project that created with Java 17. even added the spring.web module in the module-info.java file there is an error when the application is built with javafx:jlink like this.

```bash
Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: spring.web from file:///C:/Users/mafei/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.1.1/spring-web-6.1.1.jar
```

how to sort out this problem?

Comment: you've got to wait for the authors to release a JPMS module for the library in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`jlink` cannot link automatic modules (as of Java 21)**

As noted by Naman in comments:

> you've got to wait for the authors to release a JPMS module for the library in use

This is because `jlink` does not support linking [automatic modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module).

**Alternatives**

- Manually create and add module-info to existing jar files. For all direct *and transitive* dependencies that do not include defined module-info OR
- Find and use a tool which creates and adds module-info to existing jar files OR
- Choose not to define the automatic modules as required modules and instead include them on the classpath rather than the module path.

  - Requires customizing the produced jlink image to include the required non-modular jar files, and the jlink runtime launch script to place those jar files on the classpath.

For information on some of these options see the related question:

- [How to fix "auto module name cannot be used with jlink"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593369/how-to-fix-auto-module-name-cannot-be-used-with-jlink/77598710#77598710)

**When using Spring (as of Spring 6.1)**

Unfortunately, for Spring modules, waiting for the Spring developers to define JPMS modules with `module-info.java` for their software may take a very long time (or not happen at all) <sup>1</sup>.

I recommend an alternative approach. For example, make your application non-modular, use JavaFX as modules (the easiest way to do that is to use a JDK that includes JavaFX such as Azul or Liberica "JDK FX" or "Full JDK"), and package your software using jpackage (which unfortunately is more complicated to use than jlink, cannot produce cross-platform packages and produces different packaging than jlink).

---

<sup>1</sup> The tracking issue for adding support for jlink to Spring (by defining module-info files for the framework) is [Declare Spring modules with JDK 9 module metadata SPR-13501 #18079](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18079). This is currently an open issue for the Spring framework raised on Sep 24, 2015, and part of the 6.x backlog (so not currently scheduled for delivery in an upcoming release)