# How do I get JavaFx app to recognize a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

My JavaFx app (Java 21, OpenJFX 21) won't recognize a dependency and I don't know why.  The dependency is listed as the first entry in my pom's dependencies.

**EDIT:  the dependency org.mrpc.CommonUtilities is something I wrote and is in my local repository.**

My pom.xml file is:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>CommonUtilities</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>11.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
        <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
        <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>12.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My module-info.java file is (the classpath of my dependency is org.mrpc.utilities):

```
module org.sperbolink.monthlyfinances {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires net.synedra.validatorfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires org.mrpc.utilities;

    opens org.sperbolink.monthlyfinances to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.sperbolink.monthlyfinances;
}
```

A maven dependency:tree shows:

```
[INFO] org.sperbolink:MonthlyFinances:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.mrpc:CommonUtilities:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:win:21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:21:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:win:21:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:21:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:win:21:compile
```

And the error from a maven is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project MonthlyFinances: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /D:/NonGitRepo/MonthlyFinances/src/main/java/module-info.java:[10,22] module not found: org.mrpc.utilities
```

Comment: What has JavaFx to do with a Maven error?

Comment: What is `org.mrpc.CommonUtilities`?  There doesn't seem to be anything on the Internet regarding this. Is it something you created?  There's not enough information here for anybody to help you.

Comment: Maven Central has no artifacts with the group ID `org.mrpc`: https://central.sonatype.com/search?q=g%3Aorg.mrpc. Where is this library located?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the fact that org.mrpc.CommonUtilities is something I wrote that is in my local repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you the error:

```
module not found: org.mrpc.utilities
```

There is no module named `org.mrpc.utilities` on your module path.

When you require a module in your project's `module-info.java` it needs to be a valid module which is on the module path.

What is the *java* module name (not package name, jar name or maven artifact name) of the module you wrote, which is contained in the dependency artifact `CommonUtilities`?

There are three options:

1. It will appear in the `module-info.java` that you created when you wrote the module contained in the `CommonUtilities` jar.
2. If there is no module info, then the module name will appear in the `Automatic-Module-Name` in the `META-INF` of the `CommonUtilities` jar.
3. If there is no automatic name defined in the META-INF, then the assigned automatic module name is `CommonUtilities`, the same as the jar name.

To understand more see:

- [What is an automatic module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module)

In general, if you want software that you create to be treated as a full module rather than as an automatic module, then provide that software with an appropriate `module-info.java` which names the module and use that same module name when you require or otherwise make use of the module.

Comment: Thanks!  Option #3 solved the problem.  The JAR dependency is just an old school JAR of utilities that wasn't build using modules.