# How to list all dependencies that use filename-based naming (automodules)?

Tags: maven, java-module

According to [What does "Required filename-based automodules detected." warning mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46501047/14731) Maven warns about projects that depend upon automatic modules (libraries whose module name is derived from their filename).

1. How are we supposed to figure out *which* dependency is triggering this error?
2. Do we need to worry about transitive dependencies or only immediate dependencies?

For example, the latest version of Guava defines `Automatic-Module-Name` but its dependencies do not. Consequently, should projects that `requires` Guava avoid publishing to Maven Central?

**Update**: Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-366

Comment: 1. Does `jdeps --list-deps` help in what you're looking for? 2. Shouldn't worry about transitive dependencies(maven) unless they are used in your module(java).

Comment: @nullpointer `jdeps --list-deps` lists the modules I `requires` but it does not tell me which ones are automatic modules. Also building up the `module-path` of dependencies manually is not fun at all :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suspecting as well. Let's wait for figuring out how is `maven-compiler-plugin` intervening with ModuleResolution to figure out what all are automatic modules.