# Maven warns me about `filename-based automodules` even thought I've defined stable name

Tags: java, maven, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I have a very simple project written in Java 11 with just one class. I want to package it using Maven. During compilation step Maven prints warning:

> "Required filename-based automodules detected. Please don't publish
>   this project to a public artifact repository!"

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501047/what-does-required-filename-based-automodules-detected-warning-mean) I found information that I should add `Automatic-Module-Name` entry to the manifest file but unfortunately, it doesn't help. I still get that warning.

Do you an idea what else might be wrong? What should I do to make Maven happy?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.padamski</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pgs-soft</groupId>
      <artifactId>HttpClientMock</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Automatic-Module-Name>com.padamski.test</Automatic-Module-Name>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and module-info.java

```
module com.padamski.test {
    requires java.net.http;
}
```

Comment: And where is `module-info.java` located?