# What's the difference between requires and requires transitive statements in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, requires, module-info

What's the difference between ***requires*** and ***requires transitive*** module statements in module declaration?
For example:

```
module foo {
    requires java.base;
    requires transitive java.compiler;
}
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

### Readability recap

If module *bar* `requires` module *drink*, then the module system...

- enforces the presence of *drink* (called *reliable configuration*)
- allows *bar* to read *drink* (called [*readability*](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#dependencies-readability))
- allows code in *bar* to access public classes in exported packages in *drink* (called [*accessibility*](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#exports-accessibility))

Exactly the same happens if *bar* `requires transitive drink` - *drink* must be present, can be read and accessed. In fact, for *bar* and *drink* the `transitive` keyword doesn't change anything.

### Implied readability

The modules **depending on *bar*** are the ones that are impacted by `transitive`: Any module that reads *bar* can also read *drink*. In other words readability of *drink* is **implied** (which is why this is called [*implied readability*](https://blog.codefx.org/java/implied-readability/)). A consequence is that *customer* can access *drink*'s types.

So if `bar requires transitive drink` and `customer requires bar`, then *customer* can read *drink* even though it doesn't explicitly depend on it.

### Use cases

But why? Imagine you have a module whose public API accepts or returns another module's type. Let's say the *bar* module publicly returns instances of `Drink`, an interface from the *drink* module:

```
// in module _bar_
public class Bar {

    // `Drink` comes from the module _drink_,
    // which _bar_ requires
    public Drink buyDrink() { /* ... */ }

}
```

In this example, *bar* uses a regular `requires` for *drink*. Now say, *customer* depends on *bar*, so all its code can call `Bar::buyDrink`. But what happens when it does?

The module system complains that *customer* does not read *drink* and can hence not access `Drink`. To fix that, *customer* would also have to depend on *drink*. What a chore! How useless is a bar that you can't use straight away?

[image: customer requires bar requires drink - but how does customer read drink?]

For this reason, implied readability was introduced: to make a module that uses another module's types in its own public API instantly usable *without* requiring the caller to hunt down and require all involved modules.

So if `bar requires transitive drink`, *customer* can start buying drinks without having to `require drink` - `require bar` suffices. As it should.

Comment: I found your bar-drink-customer example the best one! Thanks for fixing this knowledge in my brain

Comment: I have two modules and one of them uses Jackson Annotations to annotate some classes. The other one uses Jackson to actually serialize/deserialize those annotated classes from the other module. However, the latter module complains that the classes are not annotated although they clearly are. I use `requires` in the module exporting those classes. Does this answer apply to my case also?

Comment: @AmirhoseinAl Since reflection is involved, you probably need to [open packages](https://dev.java/learn/reflective-access-with-open-modules-and-open-packages/). I recommend to give that a try and if it doesn't work, ask a new question (if there isn't one for your use case, already).

Comment: This is the simplest and best explanation so far. And they say alcohol is not a solution. +1

Answer (score 18):

Primary difference between the two is the access of a dependent module from one to another.

> If one module exports a package containing a type whose signature
>   refers to a package in a second module then the declaration of the
>   first module should include a `requires transitive` dependence upon
>   the second. This ***will ensure that other modules that depend upon the
>   first module will automatically be able to read the second module*** and,
>   hence, access all the types in that module’s exported packages.

---

So let's say for your use case :-

```
module foo {
    requires java.base;
    requires transitive java.compiler;
}
```

~> Any module that depends upon the `foo` module will automatically read the `java.compiler` module

~> On the other hand to access the module `java.base`, they must specify a `requires` clause again.

```
module bar {
    requires foo; // java.compiler is available to read
    requires java.base; // still required
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`requires` describes the process of resolution on how modules are dependent on each other.

**[Quoting line](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/package-summary.html)**

> ***A 'requires' directive (irrespective of 'transitive') expresses that
>   one module depends on some other module.*** The effect of the
>   ***'transitive' modifier is to cause additional modules to also depend on
>   the other module***. If module M 'requires transitive N', then not only
>   does M depend on N, but any module that depends on M also depends on
>   N. This allows M to be refactored so that some or all of its content
>   can be moved to a new module N without breaking modules that have a
>   'requires M' directive.

In short :

`requires` - M module depends on some other module N.

`requires transitive` - additional modules implicitly depends on the other module. Eg:, If M module depends on N, and other module P depends on M. Then, it is implicitly dependent on N as well.

Answer (score 2):

Nicolai has explained in detail. I'm just giving a specific example from JDK code here. Consider the jdk.scripting.nashorn module. The module-info of this module is as follows:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/nashorn/file/17cc754c8936/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/module-info.java

It has this line:

```
requires transitive java.scripting;
```

This is because [jdk.scripting.nashorn](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk.scripting.nashorn-summary.html) module's own API in [jdk.scripting.api.scripting](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/package-summary.html) package accepts/returns types from [javax.script](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) package of the [java.scripting](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.scripting-summary.html) module. So jdk.scripting.nashorn tells the JMPS that any module that depends on jdk.scripting.nashorn automatically depends on java.scripting module as well!

Now, the same jdk.scripting.nashorn module uses this line:

```
    requires jdk.dynalink;
```

for another module [jdk.dynalink](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk.dynalink-summary.html). That is because *none* of the exported packages (the "API") from jdk.scripting.nashorn module uses types from jdk.dynalink module. The use of jdk.dynalink by jdk.scripting.nashorn is purely an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification for Java 9 explains it in very simple terms. From the section on [Module Dependences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.1):

> The `requires` directive specifies the name of a module on which the current module has a dependence.
>
> ...
>
> The `requires` keyword may be followed by the modifier `transitive`. **This causes any module which `requires` the current module to have an implicitly declared dependence on the module specified by the `requires transitive` directive.**

In other words:

- if module X `requires` module Y,
- and module Y `requires transitive` module Z,
- then module X also (implicitly) `requires` module Z.

Answer (score 0):

The term *accessibility* is ambiguous: you can access objects without access to their type. If an object is of type T that lies in a package that is not exported and if an "exported" code has a method that returns a T ... Then when invoking this method you get a handle on this T object (and you can invoke on it any methods that pertains to any type known to your code).

*readability* is also ambiguous: it does not mean your ClassLoader will always be unable to load the (unexported) T class.

Answer (score 0):

the difference between requires and requires transitive has been explained above hence I will only add effects of requires transitive

- if (module m requires transitive n) && (module L requires m) then module L cannot be compiled or executed without access to module n
- if (module m requires transitive n) && (module L requires both m and n) then module L doesn't need to explicitly declare requires for n