# Does maven add all dependencies to modulepath by default?

Tags: maven, java-module, java-platform-module-system, maven-compiler-plugin, module-path

I read on [Java 9 Modularity](https://books.google.gr/books?id=J5Q0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=maven+modulepath&source=bl&ots=6ZcOQCy8Sg&sig=ACfU3U0VGJomKOLhebwUkTt6SISKzBpxVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3jsmL0JfqAhUDJBoKHf04DKQQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=maven%20modulepath&f=false) book:

> **Dependencies are always put on the module path**, even when dependency isn't modularized yet.
>
> [...]
> The most important changes made to Apache Maven for support of the Java module system are as follows:
>
> - **Uses the modulepath during compilation**
> - Supports a mix of explicit modules and automatic modules as dependencies

I'm looking at maven documentation and I cannot find this information anywhere.

Does maven by default add `<dependencies>` to the `modulepath` (only?) and if yes, after which maven version?

Also if the above is true is there a way to instruct maven to not use `modulepath` at all?

Comment: doesn't "after which maven version?" become insignificant, if compatibility is ensured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Maven puts dependencies to module path only for those Maven modules that have module descriptors (`module-info.java`). Non-modular Maven modules still put their dependencies to classpath.

You can run Maven with `-X` option to see exact command-line options that are passed to `javac`.

Comment: Well, the OP reminded me of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46571387/1746118 and I guess the unnamed modules aspect is missed out in this answer?

Comment: @Naman It looks like you're right. The dependencies that are not referenced in `module-info.java` (or transitively referenced) are put on classpath. However, I don't think this is super important here since we are talking about compile time. I can't imagine where that would make a difference.